# Spring Boot internationalization works for French but not Korean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, utf-8, spring-internationalization

I have `messages_ko.properties` file and I set my browser to Korean. It loads up the page using the message file but the internationalized text is all question marks.

```
????? ...
```

It looks like Korean in the Eclipse editor. The file editor is set to UTF-8. My Google Chrome is able to display Korean. This whole page http://www.hyundaigroup.com/ is in Korean. I used

```
curl -H "Accept-Language: ko" localhost:8080/page
```

And the internationalized text is mostly question marks still. I opened the `messages_ko.properties` file in Notepad++ and it shows Korean and that it's encoded in UTF-8.

It works fine when I set my browser to French. Non-English characters (`Intéressé`) show up fine.  The HTML is marked as UTF-8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

So why is Spring Boot mangling the Korean characters but not the French?

I'm using an `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`.

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver ahlr = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
    ahlr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return ahlr;
}
```

And I'm using Spring Messages and JSP to print the internationalized text.

```
<spring:message code="title"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the server response header was

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

I added

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

To the top of the page and then it worked.